# name of log(n+1) plot

Tags: distribution, logarithmic

I am trying to plot a distribution of positive integers which contains a lot of variance. I opted to use the log of the y-values but that causes issues due to the inclusion of zeros. I though of plotting `log10(n+1)`, but it seems a bit janky.

Is this solution used more often?
Does it have a name?
Is there a better/more common method?

Comment: Why do any transformation at all? In other words, what do you want your transformation to accomplish?

Comment: @Dave Log(0) amounts to minus infinity, which is hard to plot. By making all values at least 1, I assure that the log is always positive without ignoring the zeros outright.

Comment: But why transform at all? Why not plot the original values?

Comment: @Dave because 10 and 1000 are hard to distinguish while 1 and 3 aren't. I'll probably not use this method as I expect it to cause confusion, but it seemed like an obvious solution so I wondered if it had a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a standard name, but it does appear to be fairly common.  Programmatically, it's often implemented as `log1p` ("log of 1 plus").

- [stats.SE "Plotting 0 in a log scaled axis"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/58129/232706)
- [stats.SE "Interpreting log-log regression with log(1+x) as independent variable"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/576504/232706), asking about regression with log1p
- [SAS blog "Log transformations: How to handle negative data values?"](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/04/27/log-transformations-how-to-handle-negative-data-values.html), suggests $\log(1+\epsilon)$

There's also the "symlog" or "log-modulus" functions when you really care about negative values as well:

- [SAS blog "A log transformation of positive and negative values"](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/07/14/log-transformation-of-pos-neg.html) puts forward $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\log(1+|x|)$ as "log-modulus" function
- [SO "What is the origin of Matplotlib's symlog (a.k.a. symmetrical log) scale?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39988048/10495893)
- [SO "Logscale plots with zero values in matplotlib"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16904755/10495893), the answer suggests symlog, but a linked duplicate has an answer suggesting log1p